# JDBI query returning the wrong value for MSSQL datetimeoffset(4) column?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbi

Very weirdly I have found that my JDBI query from my MSSQL database is returning the wrong value for a column of type `datetimeoffset(4)`. In the database I have a single row (I removed all other rows for sanity's sake)

```
ID | Datetimeoffset 
------------------------------------
1  | 2016-01-19 22:03:17.0309 -05:00
```

When I run the below in Java, it prints out `2016-01-17 22:12:50.7357 -05:00`, a very different time than the value in my DB. I'm guessing that somewhere in JDBI it tries to parse the column value into a `DATETIMEOFFSET` and gets confused somehow?

Also, when I convert the retrieved value to a `java.sql.Timestamp` object and look at the milliseconds value, it is about 2 days prior to the current     `System.currentTimeMillis()`

```
tblDao.getRow(1)

@RegisterMapper(RowMapper.class)
public interface TblDao {
   @SqlQuery("SELET ID, Datetimeoffset FROM tbl WHERE ID = :id")  
   Row getRow(@Bind("id") Long id);
 }

public class RowMapper implements ResultSetMapper<Treatment> {

@Override
public Row map(int index, ResultSet resultSet, StatementContext statementContext ) throws SQLException {

    Object timestampObj = resultSet.getObject("CreatedDatetimeoffset");
    system.println(timestampObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that this issue was due to the SqlServerDriver. When run on a machine with version 4.0 the proper `datetimeoffset` value was returned by query; the wrong value was being returned by a machine with version 3.0.